# Does Ubuntu have a “boot override” function like in the Win10 recovery options?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bootable-media

Windows 10 has a function to boot from a USB Flash Drive after restart using some kind of "boot override" function, which probably bypasses the usual boot order in the BIOS.

Can I find something similar in Linux?

Comment: Booting from external media has nothing to do with installed OS: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/boot-surface-from-a-usb-device-fe7a7323-8d1d-823d-be17-9aec89c4f9f5

Comment: In ideal world…any help?! link provides nothing

Comment: It sure does! It says how to boot to the UEFI settings by pressing and holding the volume-up button while booting.

Comment: No, this not working. Tested thousand of time over 3 years. Only way I could access usb boot was from windows and this option (by having only Ubuntu installed) is now gone

Comment: Okay, we know this now, but how was someone supposed to know that until now? When you ask a question, you need to clearly spell out what you tried and what was the result when you tried that.

Comment: Either you're doing something wrong (very likely) or you have some hardware issue (much less likely). Anyway, if you installed Ubuntu correctly in UEFI mode you DO have the same option, you just have to make the Grub menu visible at boot (it usually isn't with only Ubuntu installed). There you'll have an option to open UEFI settings. Nevertheless if the NORMAL method as explained in the link doesn't work when done correctly, you need to have it serviced, end of story.

Comment: Well, I can access BIOS easily, that’s not an issue. Issue is as I write - i can not boot from USB - despite proper boot sequence is set (USB like first) . System is simply ignoring it. GRUB menu I have visible, but it’s too late to access bootable USB once it’s loaded. Also-bootable usb is 100% correct as I’ve installed Ubuntu from it at first place

Comment: Is or was at the time. It can become corrupt at any time. So, again, please3 [edit] the question to post all the relevant information in the question itself. We now know a different thing that we didn't know before after being mislead twice. Comments are NOT for this.

Comment: all additional info in the comments from me is obvious or not so relevant. Anyhow I’m desperate, so I do

Comment: It can't be stressed enough you need to make sure the Windows installation media actually works. Is this what you're trying to boot, isn't it? How was it made? Have you tried in another computer to confirmit boots? This info is ALL relevant and is your job to provide it, not for us to have an endless back and forth to get it. Also you should thoroughly READ the Microsoft link because it has a LOT of information about settings that you MUST confirm otherwise it won't  boot from external media, period. And all of this is because 1. you think you know what you're doing (...)

Comment: (...) and somehow what you posted makes sense to you but doesn't to anyone with just basic experience (this is about this question and at least an older one). 2. you need to understand that NO OS or recovery mode, whatever is required to boot external media; what you might have tried in the past is Win10's direct link to boot from USB but what it does is nothing more than trigger a boot override option that's also available in UEFI settings, there's no magic whatsoever; if the media boots with that option it boots by following the instructions in in the first comment, (...)

Comment: (...) there's absolutely no discussion possible about that, everybody with minimal experience knows that. 3. having a properly tested Windows installation media and assuring all the conditions mentioned in the Microsoft document (and there are a few that can and will prevent booting from external media) are met, the Windows installation WILL start. If you can't manege it then take to a professional service. We're all volunteers here, don't give us attitude, over and out.

Comment: @YisroelTech How happy are you now about the downvote reversal? Just curious...

Comment: Has linux - as you call it “boot override function” ? That’s all what I need. // rest what you said is relevant but as you also know -  not helpful. Oh, and if you read my comments, youll find out that I tested to boot linux which actually worked as Ive been installing it from it. Thank all who's ego wasn’t touched. Stay strong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by using `efibootmgr` to change the EFI firmware's 'BootNext' parameter.

For example, to boot into Windows once, set 'BootNext' to the entry you want, then reboot:

```
# efibootmgr
 BootCurrent: 0001
 BootOrder: 0000,0001
 Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
 Boot0001* Ubuntu
 Boot001F  USB HDD

# efibootmgr --bootnext 0000
# reboot
```

Generally, the firmware will only add removable devices to this list if they were present during system boot. Even with Windows, a USB stick that's plugged in later will not show up in the list (unless you do a normal reboot first).

You can also rearrange the entries permanently, using `--bootorder 0001,0000` or such.

To reboot into the *firmware settings* screen, a different method is used (the 'OsIndications' parameter – older systems might not support this):

```
# systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
```

The functions are also accessible via CLI from Windows:

| Linux | Windows |
| --- | --- |
| `efibootmgr` | `bcdedit /enum firmware` |
| `efibootmgr --bootnext NUM` | `bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} bootsequence GUID` |
| `efibootmgr --bootorder NUM…` | `bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} displayorder GUID…` |
| `reboot`, `systemctl reboot` | `shutdown /r /t 0` |
| `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` | `shutdown /r /fw /t 0` |

(Normally `bcdedit` deals with the Windows Boot Manager's own menu, but these specific commands ask it to manage the EFI boot menu instead.)

Comment: This seems exactly what I was looking for. I’ll test it soon and write back. Thank you!!

Comment: Man, you’re amazing! Thank you very much. Working like charm!