# Using grub and MS boot loader

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader

Hi all so I have a question with regards to booting my os’.
I use Linux (Ubuntu22.04) and Windows11 - ON TWO HARDRIVES/SSD’s. I have the boot setup such that msbootloader takes me into w11 by default and the 2nd drive for Linux.

I have a shortcut in W11 to send me straight to bios from desktop so that I can select Linux and when in Linux naturally I just restart to get back to windows.

Issue/preference 1: I would like to not have to select the second drive (Linux) when in bios. Can I modify/create a new shortcut to punch me straight through to the secondary boot device? Eg. Not have to select boot menu-and pick secondary device.

Issue/preference 2: what tool slash modification in boot settings do I have to make to get the bootloader  to ask me every time? I’m not sure whether I will do this but it’s a thought I keep having.

Comment: GRUB typically chainloads to the Windows boatloader manager and most people are perfectly happy in using it as is for dual-booting. No need to open UEFI settings, ever, unless for troubleshooting purposes. That's how modern systems work, particularly when Windows 11 is involved as it supports ONLY UEFI mode sGRUB typically chainloads to the Windows boatloader manager and most people are perfectly happy in using it as is for dual-booting. No need to open UEFI settings, ever, unless for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Except for people who want BitLocker to work reliably, as Windows doesn't support BitLocker's "Secure Boot" mode when chainloaded via anything third-party...

Comment: That's how modern systems work, particularly when Windows 11 is involved as it supports UEFI mode ONLY! In UEFI mode all bootloaders coexist in the ESP (EFI System Partition) and can be used independently. This is irrespective of where the OSes are installed (your all caps part is moot, irrelevant, and shows a lack of understanding about UEFI mode).

Comment: @u1686_grawity Indeed, but not the case here, just an awfully persistent way of doing things like pre-UEFI times...

Comment: Does https://superuser.com/a/1785545/1686 or https://superuser.com/a/1781293/1686 answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you right : you can try creating a desktop shortcut with such command bellow :

> but it depend on the path to the Linux bootloader and your specific Linux distribution and installation configuration. Make sure to adjust the command to your specifications :

```
shutdown.exe /r /fw /t 0 && bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

This command will first restart the computer and boot into the firmware setup utility, and then set the boot path to the Linux bootloader.

Click "OK" to save the changes and proceed into loading your linux .

---

> ⚠️ **IMPORTANT** ! :  
>  ----------------- 
> i don't have ( linux + windows ) to test it, so Experiment the code on your own risk 
> **also keep in mind** modifying the boot configuration can have unintended consequences and may potentially cause issues with your system. Make sure to create a backup of your important data and test it on empty systems not on computers that you have important works on.
>
> ---

Comment: Thanks for your help I’m a relative newbie to this so I don’t fully understand all of the terminology. After I tweaked last time I no longer see grub I just get hp bios selection of device to boot from so maybe I assumed that I no longer used grub if I had the opportunity to jump to grub boot selection from my desktop shortcut that would be great and maybe have boot selection show up from first startup would be better